# Why didn't reducing my water pressure regulator affect the outside spigot pressure?

Tags: plumbing, repair, water

My water pressure reading from outside water faucet reads 110-120. I reduced on my water pressure regulator and can feel inside the water pressure is decreased but the readings outside remain the same. Possible reasons? Water pressure in the house feels to low now and can’t imagine it’s in the range I get outside on the readings.

Comment: Where is the pressure regulator located? Is this a well or s municipal water system?

Comment: Down in basement right next to shut off valve. Municipal

Comment: Are you certain that the outside faucet is not tied into the waterline before it reaches the regulator?

Comment: I thought that as well and I think the one in the front of the house might be. But we have one in the back which reads the same. Can’t imagine both are or maybe?

Comment: Does shutoff valve in basement shut off outside faucets?

Comment: Will need to check that...will advise back tomorrow. Could find my answer quick thanks!

Comment: Are regulators effective at lowering the pressure when there's no flow? My guess is quite often no. The one I've got for my garden would let you read high pressure, but as soon as there's any flow then the pressure reading drops. So, it waters as if there was low pressure, but once I close the valve, a pressure reading still reads high.